# Spring Boot Cloud + Hashi Consul + Connect Proxy : How to configure bootstrap for config?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

I am putting together a proof-of-concept using the latest spring boot, HashiCorp Consul & Connect.  Basically, I want to show how webflux web services can use Consul for configuration and use Consul's mesh for secured communications.  So, the latter is working with the following configuration, but the webflux service cannot get its configuration from Consul.  I assume that the settings in bootstrap.yml for Spring Cloud Consul Config would be to the sidecar, but the connection fails.  I've tried a lot of alternatives, and have hit a dead end.  I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you for your help and time!
Mike

=================== ORIGINAL INFORMATION =====================

```
# Dependencies
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Hoxton.SR9"
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-all")
}
```

```
# Error when the service launches in k8s
Setting Active Processor Count to 8
Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx1661599K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128352K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 2G, Thread Count: 50, Loaded Class Count: 20247, Headroom: 0%)
Adding 138 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
Spring Cloud Bindings Enabled
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -agentpath:/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jvmkill/jvmkill-1.16.0-RELEASE.so=printHeapHistogram=1 -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx1661599K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128352K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
2020-11-12 01:15:15.066  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef83abed] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)
2020-11-12 01:15:22.779 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2020-11-12 01:15:23.783 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2020-11-12 01:15:24.885 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2020-11-12 01:15:26.097 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2020-11-12 01:15:27.432 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2020-11-12 01:15:28.900 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2020-11-12 01:15:28.917 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8501 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

```
# Relevant bootstrap.yml
server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

spring:
  application:
    name: k8sconsulwebflux
  profiles: development
  cloud:
    consul:
      # Using Consul Connect Service Mesh
      scheme: https
      host: localhost
      port: 8501
```

```
# Custom Helm Setting for Hashi Consul
global:
  name: "consul-"
  image: "consul:1.8.5"
  imageK8S: "hashicorp/consul-k8s:latest"
  domain: consul
  datacenter: csc
  gossipEncryption:
    secretName: "gossip-encryption-key"
    secretKey: "key"
  tls:
    enabled: true
    enableAutoEncrypt: true
  acls:
    manageSystemACLs: true
  lifecycleSidecarContainer:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "25Mi"
        cpu: "20m"
      limits:
        memory: "50Mi"
        cpu: "20m"
  imageEnvoy: "envoyproxy/envoy-alpine:v1.14.4"
server:
  replicas: 1
  bootstrapExpect: 1
  disruptionBudget:
    enabled: true
    maxUnavailable: 0
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "100Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
    limits:
      memory: "100Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
client:
  enabled: true
  grpc: true
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "100Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
    limits:
      memory: "100Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
  updateStrategy: |
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 2
    type: RollingUpdate
# Enable the Consul Web UI via a NodePort
ui:
  enabled: true
  service:
    type: 'NodePort'
syncCatalog:
  enabled: true
  default: true
  consulPrefix: "k8s-"
  k8sPrefix: "consul-"
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "50Mi"
      cpu: "50m"
    limits:
      memory: "50Mi"
      cpu: "50m"
  logLevel: debug

# Enable Connect for secure communication between nodes
connectInject:
  enabled: true
  default: true
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "50Mi"
      cpu: "50m"
    limits:
      memory: "50Mi"
      cpu: "50m"
  centralConfig:
    enabled: true
  sidecarProxy:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 100Mi
        cpu: 100m
      limits:
        memory: 100Mi
        cpu: 100m
  initContainer:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "25Mi"
        cpu: "50m"
      limits:
        memory: "150Mi"
        cpu: "50m"
```

=================== UPDATED INFORMATION 1 =====================

After making the changes that Blake suggested, my app has moved passed the initial issue and on to a weird TLS/SSL issue...  Arggg!  I'd appreciate any suggestions.  At this point, Consul is configured to handle the ssl configuration, so I am surprised about the error...  This error is happening in my minikube "cluster" and in a real k8s cluster at AKS.

I've published the simple, proof-of-concept demo at gitlab, in case someone would like to take a closer look:

https://gitlab.com/abitofhelp.shared/spring-consul-proxy-k8s.git

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)
2020-11-12 06:55:42.529 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2020-11-12 06:55:42.541 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:83) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
```

Comment: Don't connect to the mesh, but the agent in 8500

Answer (score 1):

You'll first want to configure your application to connect to the IP of the local Consul agent which is running on the Kubernetes worker node instead of localhost. You can use the Kubernetes downward API to inject the IP of host as an environment variable for your pod.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: example
      image: myapp
      env:
        - name: HOST_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
      command: <command to start application>
```

(see https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/installation/install#accessing-the-consul-http-api for more info)

Then reference this `HOST_IP` environment variable in your `bootstrap.yaml` configuration.

```yaml
server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

spring:
  application:
    name: k8sconsulwebflux
  profiles: development
  cloud:
    consul:
      # Using Consul Connect Service Mesh
      scheme: https
      host: ${HOST_IP}
      port: 8501
      # Since ACLs are enabled, you also need to include a token
      # with appropriate permissions
      config:
        acl-token: 12345678-9876-5432-1234-567898765432
```

Comment: Wow!  You rock, Blake!  I will give it a whirl and report back. :)

Comment: Hi Blake, Your suggestion resolved my issue, but now I am getting an SSL error when the app starts.  This surprised me since Consul is handling all of the certs...  I've posted an update below the initial issue, and have posted the demo project at gitlab, in case someone would like to see the code.  Straight-forward demo...  https://gitlab.com/abitofhelp.shared/spring-consul-proxy-k8s.git

Comment: Your container needs to be configured to trust the Consul root CA. There's not a well documented way to do this, although a few folks have figured out a method that works for their needs. See the discussion on [Document how to make calls to Consul API when TLS is enabled](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm/issues/474), or my personal notes on [Accessing the Consul API from within a Kubernetes pod](https://gist.github.com/blake/f3b9b680b70024ccfd9bcd04c8feef45). Hopefully one of these methods will suffice for your use case.